# How to get MySQL Update to work

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'm trying to get the mySQL update to work below and there's no console error but it doesn't reflect any changes I have made to the database.

Please let me know if i miss out anything.

Appreciate it very much.

table 1: nmc_cd

[image]

table 2: nmc_category

[image]

table 3: nmc_publisher

[image]

In this update php, it gets the values from the previous php and update the table.

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');

include 'database_conn.php';        // make db connection

  $pCDTitle = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDTitle') ? $_GET['CDTitle']: null;         // store all parameter in variable
  $pCDPubName = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDPub') ? $_GET['CDPub']: null;
  $pCDYear = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDYear') ? $_GET['CDYear']: null;
  $pCDCategory = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDCat') ? $_GET['CDCat']: null;        
  $pCDPrice = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDPrice') ? $_GET['CDPrice']: null;
  $pCDID = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDID') ? $_GET['CDID']: null;
  $pCDPubID = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'pubID') ? $_GET['pubID']: null;

  $sql = "UPDATE nmc_cd "
     . "SET nmc_cd.CDTitle='$pCDTitle',nmc_cd.CDYear='$pCDYear',nmc_cd.CDPrice='$pCDPrice',nmc_cd.catID='$pCDCategory',nmc_cd.pubID='$pCDPubName'"
     . "WHERE nmc_cd.CDID='$pCDID'";

  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<b><font face='verdana' font sise='3' color='red'>Record updated successfully</font></b>";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM nmc_cd "
     . "JOIN nmc_category ON (nmc_cd.catID = nmc_category.catID)"
     . "JOIN nmc_publisher ON (nmc_cd.pubID = nmc_publisher.pubID)"
     . "WHERE nmc_cd.CDID = '$pCDID'"; //Query Database
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
     $CDID = $row['CDID'];
     $CDTitle = $row['CDTitle'];
     $CDYear = $row['CDYear'];
     $CDPrice = $row['CDPrice'];
     $catDesc = $row['CDCat'];
     $pubName = $row['CDPub'];
     $location = $row['location'];

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Title</th><th>Year</th><th>Price</th><th>Catergory</th><th>Publisher</th><th>Location</th></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>".$row["CDTitle"]."</td><td> ".$row["CDYear"]."</td><td> ".$row["CDPrice"]."</td><td> ".$row["CatCD"]."</td><td> ".$row["CatPub"]."</td><td> ".$row["location"]."</td></tr>"; //Display Data Table Data
echo "</table"; 
mysqli_close($conn);
} else {
    echo "<b><font face='verdana' color='red'>Error updating record!!!</font></b>" . $conn->error;
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry I shorten to just the SQL Update php which isn't working

Comment: Thnaks, but wouldn't at the bottom where the echo $row would have gotten it from $sql ?

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);